# Python script to manage elasticsearch backups

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch

The following is a Python 3 script I wrote to take and delete elasticsearch snapshots. Could anyone please point out any issues? I am concerned that I have structured the code poorly (particularly the order of the functions), making it hard to read, but I am unsure how to fix that.

I also made no real attempt to write *pythonic* code. Any ways I could improve the code to be more pythonic would also be appreciated.

[GitHub](https://github.com/combatdud3/elasticsearch_backup)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def main():
    import argparse, logging

    # Parse arguments
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Take subcommands and \
    parameters for elasticsearch backup script.')
    parser.add_argument('function', type=str, choices=['backup','delete'],
    help='Triggers a new elasticsearch action.')
    parser.add_argument('--config', type=str,
    help='Specify path to a config file.')
    parser.add_argument('--name', type=str, help='Specify snapshot name')
    parser.add_argument('--age', type=int,
    help='Specify age to delete backups after')
    parser.add_argument('--logfile', type=str,
    help='Specify where to put a logfile')
    parser.add_argument('--loglevel', type=str, help='Specify log level',
    choices=['INFO', 'DEBUG', 'WARNING', 'ERROR', 'CRITICAL'])

    args = parser.parse_args()

    # Find config file, and read in config
    config = find_config(args.config)

    # Check if logfile was specified
    if args.logfile == None:
        logfile = '/var/log/elasticsearch/snapshot_backup.log'
    else:
        logfile = args.logfile

    # Check if logging level was specified
    try:
        if args.loglevel != None:
            logging_level = logging.getLevelName(args.loglevel)
            print('I am args: {0}'.format(logging_level))
        elif config['logging_level'] != None:
            logging_level = logging.getLevelName(config['logging_level'])
            print('I am config: {0}'.format(logging_level))
    except KeyError as e:
        logging_level = logging.getLevelName('ERROR')

    # Set up logging
    logging.basicConfig(filename=logfile, level=logging_level,
    format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

    # Map argument string to function name
    FUNCTION_MAP = {'backup': backup, 'delete': delete}

    # Initialise callable variable using the FUNCTION_MAP
    func = FUNCTION_MAP[args.function]

    # Call funky voodoo variable function
    if args.function == 'backup':
        func(elastic_node=config['elasticsearch_host'],
        backup_repository=config['backup_repository'], snapshot_name=args.name)
    elif args.function == 'delete':
        func(elastic_node=config['elasticsearch_host'],
        backup_repository=config['backup_repository'], snapshot_name=args.name,
        age=args.age)
    else: # Should never get here. argparse should pick this up 
        logging.error('Invalid option {}'.format(args.function))
        exit()

def find_config(config_arg):
    import yaml
    # Check if custom config defined
    if config_arg == '' or config_arg == None:
        configfile = '/etc/elasticsearch/backup.yaml'
    else:
        configfile = config_arg

    # Read in config from config file
    try:
        with open(configfile, 'r') as ymlfile:
            config = yaml.load(ymlfile)
            return(config)
    except FileNotFoundError as e:
        print(e)
        exit()

def backup(elastic_node, backup_repository, port=9200, snapshot_name=None):
    import json, logging, requests

    # Get new snapshot name if none provided
    if snapshot_name == None:
        snapshot_name = generate_snapshot_name()

    # Assemble url
    snapshot_url = 'http://{0}:{1}/_snapshot/{2}/{3}?wait_for_completion=true \
    '.format(elastic_node, port, backup_repository, snapshot_name)

    # Send REST API call
    try:
        request = requests.put(snapshot_url)
        request.raise_for_status()
        logging.info('backup: {0} completed'.format(snapshot_name))
    except ConnectionError as e:
        logging.error("backup: Failed to create {0}".format(e))
        logging.error(json.loads(request.text))
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
        logging.error("backup: Failed to create {0}".format(e))
        logging.error(json.loads(request.text)['error']['reason'])
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
        logging.error("backup: Failed to create {0}".format(e))

def delete(age, elastic_node, backup_repository, port=9200, snapshot_name=None):
    import logging, json, requests

    # If age not provided, use default
    if age == None:
        age = 40

    # If snapshot_name provided delete it
    if snapshot_name is not None:
        url = 'http://{0}:{1}/_snapshot/{2}/{3}'.format(elastic_node, port,
        backup_repository, snapshot_name)
        # Send REST API call
        try:
            request = requests.delete(url)
            request.raise_for_status()
            logging.info('delete: {0} completed'.format(snapshot_name))
        except ConnectionError as e:
            logging.error("delete: Failed to create {0}".format(e))
            logging.error(json.loads(request.text))
        except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
            logging.error("delete: Failed to create {0}".format(e))
            logging.error(json.loads(request.text)['error']['reason'])
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
            logging.error("delete: Failed to create {0}".format(e))
    # Get today's snapshot name if none provided
    else:
        snapshot_name = generate_snapshot_name()
        logging.info('delete: Generated snapshot name \
        {0}'.format(snapshot_name))
        snapshot_time_delta = calculate_delta(snapshot_name, age=age)
        bulk_delete(snapshot_time_delta, elastic_node, backup_repository,
        port)

def generate_snapshot_name(prefix='snapshot-'):
    from datetime import datetime

    # generate date string in UTC time
    date = datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y%m%d")
    snapshot_name = prefix + date
    return snapshot_name

def calculate_delta(snapshot_name=None, age=40):
    import logging, re
    from datetime import timedelta

    try:
        if snapshot_name == None:
            raise ValueError('snapshot_name cannot be None')
        else:
            date = parse_snapshot_name(snapshot_name)

            # Calculate time delta
            date_delta = date - timedelta(days=age)
            logging.info('calculate_delta: date {0} days ago is {1} \
            '.format(age, date_delta))
            return date_delta
    except ValueError as e:
        logging.error('calculate_delta: {0}}'.format(e))

def bulk_delete(snapshot_time_delta, elastic_node, backup_repository, port):
    import logging, requests

    # Fetch all snapshot metadata
    all_snapshots = fetch_all_snapshots(elastic_node, backup_repository, port)
    # Find snapshots older than snapshot_time_delta
    old_snapshots = find_old_snapshots(all_snapshots, snapshot_time_delta)

    for snapshot in old_snapshots:
        # Assemble url
        url = 'http://{0}:{1}/_snapshot/{2}/{3}'.format(elastic_node, port,
        backup_repository, snapshot)
        logging.debug('bulk_delete:  URL is: {0}'.format(url))
        # Send REST API call
        try:
            request = requests.delete(url)
            request.raise_for_status()
            logging.info('bulk_delete: {0} completed'.format(snapshot))
        except ConnectionError as e:
            logging.error("bulk_delete: Failed to create {0}".format(e))
            logging.error(json.loads(request.text))
        except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
            logging.error("bulk_delete: Failed to create {0}".format(e))
            logging.error(json.loads(request.text)['error']['reason'])
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
            logging.error("bulk_delete: Failed to create {0}".format(e))

def fetch_all_snapshots(elastic_node, backup_repository, port):
    import json, logging, requests

    # Assemble URL
    url = 'http://{0}:{1}/_snapshot/{2}/_all'.format(elastic_node, port, backup_repository)

    try:
        #Send REST API call
        request = requests.get(url)
        request.raise_for_status()
        logging.info('fetch_all_snapshots: retrieved all snapshots metadata')
        return json.loads(request.text)
    except ConnectionError as e:
        logging.error("fetch_all_snapshots: Failed to create {0}".format(e))
        logging.error(json.loads(request.text))
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
        logging.error("fetch_all_snapshots: Failed to create {0}".format(e))
        logging.error(json.loads(request.text)['error']['reason'])
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
        logging.error("fetch_all_snapshots: Failed to create {0}".format(e))

def find_old_snapshots(all_snapshots, snapshot_time_delta):
    import datetime, logging

    old_snapshots = []

    for snapshot in all_snapshots['snapshots']:
        snapshot_date = parse_snapshot_name(snapshot['snapshot'])
        logging.info('find_old_snapshots: snapshot name: {0}: snapshot date: {1}\
        '.format(snapshot['snapshot'], snapshot_date))
        if snapshot_date <= snapshot_time_delta:
            old_snapshots.append(snapshot['snapshot'])
            logging.info('find_old_snapshots: {0}'.format(old_snapshots))
    return old_snapshots

def parse_snapshot_name(snapshot_name=None):
    import logging, re
    from datetime import datetime

    try:
        if snapshot_name is None:
            raise ValueError('snapshot_name cannot be None')
        else:
            # Pull datetime out of snapshot_name
            search_result = re.search(r'\d{8}', snapshot_name)
            logging.info('parse_snapshot_name: Parsed date is: \
            {0}'.format(search_result.group()))

            #Convert regex result into datetime
            date = datetime.strptime(search_result.group(), '%Y%m%d')
            logging.info('parse_snapshot_name: Confirm parsed date converted \
            to date: {0}'.format(type(date)))
            return date
    except ValueError as e:
        logging.error('parse_snapshot_name: {0}'.format(e))
    except AttributeError as e:
        logging.info('Snapshot {0} is a manual snapshot. It cannot be deleted \
        automatically.'.format(snapshot_name))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 6):

You have at-least the following problems:

- You should put all your imports at the top of your file, just after your shebang. What you're doing makes it hard to know what you've actually imported and causes imports to be more tedious that they're meant to be.
- [Argparse allows you to set defaults](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#default), and so you don't need to implement this yourself.
- You should use `is` when comparing to singletons. And so you should use `if cond is None:` rather than `if cond == None:`. You've done this 7 times.
- You don't use some of your imports. `datetime` and `re` on line 215 and 149 respectively.
- It's advised against in [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) to import multiple modules in one import.
- `json` is never defined in `bulk_delete`, or the global scope. And so shouldn't work in this function.
- It's hard to read your `add_argument` calls, as you put `help` on the following line without extra indentation, and so looks, at a glance, that you're constantly re-defining a `help` variable.
- PEP8 advices that module level functions and classes should have two empty lines between them. This IMO makes the code cleaner and easier to read at a glance.
- You should move your large try-except blocks to be in a single `request` function. This is as they take up a large portion of your program. And make your code WET, which is *not good*. As if you ever need to change how the excepts work, you need to change all the occurrences.
- Setting defaults are easier if you overwrite a variable if it's bad with the default. Take `configfile` in `find_config`, you could instead do:

  ```
  def find_config(config_file):
      if not config_file:
          config_file = '/etc/elasticsearch/backup.yaml'

      try:
  ```

---

You should look into reading [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), and [use a linter](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5252) to follow the parts that you agree with.

And I think the way you are logging is promoting you to write bad code. And so I'd advise you write your code without logging, and then add it in afterwords.

Comment: @Pelionrayz, In your last point, seems like you tried to overwrite  config_file, don't you?

Comment: @mayo I didn't notice that, thank you! It's now fixed.